# Some thenables in a promise is not being executed

Tags: promise, bluebird

I was trying to read and parse a large csv file and for each row I had to do some async calculations and increase the counter after the operation is done. So I created a Promise `p` and try to chain many `.then(xxx)` and at the end of the csv reading it's the final `.then(yyy)` to output the counts.

However this number does not add up. But if I do `p = p.then(xxx)` and `p = p.then(yyy)` the number would add up (for smaller csv files) but I would face memory leak sometimes (for large csv files).

Is there something that I did wrong?

```
var fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('fast-csv');
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var count = 0;
var actual = 0;
let p = Promise.resolve();
const stream = fs.createReadStream(`/Users/ssmlee/Desktop/KingKong_Sims_5M.txt`);
const csvStream = csv({
    delimiter: ';'
})
.on('data', (row) => {
    count++
    if (count % 10000 === 0) {
        console.log(count)
        console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed)
    }
  p.then(() => { // instead if we do p = p.then(() => it will work correctly
    return Promise.resolve().delay(5)
    .then(function() {
        actual++
    })
  });
})
.on('end', () => {
  p.then(() => { // instead if we do p = p.then(() => it will work correctly
    console.log(actual); // 4999977 or something like this
    console.log(count); // 5000000
  });
});
stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

Comment: Why do you think that the scheme that works would leak memory?  There's nothing wrong with `p = p.then(...)`.  That structure, by itself, does not cause a memory leak.

Comment: I am doing `process.memoryUsage().heapUsed` to check my memory usage and turns out my memory is not being garbage collected. You can probably generate a random file with 5m rows and see this happening I think dunno why is that.

Comment: You're using a ton of memory because of the method you chose to implement this.  You could use a ton less memory by sequencing things appropriately rather than putting hundreds of thousands of promises in flight at the same time.  For example, you could read the first row, pause the CSV stream, do your async operation, then when it finishes release the CSV stream.  If you actually do want to do some operations in parallel to speed up end-to-end timing, but want reasonable memory usage, then you need to keep some modest number of operations in parallel at once (like perhaps 10), not 500,000.

Comment: And, I don't think this is actually memory leaks, it just takes awhile to run and finish and GC because you ran a zillion parallel operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you increase the `actual` count with a delay, but never wait for the promise (throwing the result of `then` away), the stream might end with not all increments already happened. In your example, 23 callbacks are still waiting for the 5ms delay. Btw, chaining all these on the same `p = Promise.resolve()` doesn't make much sense, you could just immediately execute everything.

If you are doing `p = p.then(…)` you build a very long promise chain. This should not leak any memory, but will use a lot of memory - all the 5ms delays are chained together sequentially, and your script will take (at least) 25000 seconds to run. The file is read in at the beginning, millions of promises are generated, then they resolve (and can be garbage collected) one after the other.

To do this sequential approach performantly, you probably should use the stream's back pressure system.

But you can also await the delays in parallel, having not too many alive promises at a time:

```
p = Promise.all([p, Promise.delay(5)]).then(() => {
  actual++;
});
```

Comment: My understanding is for both cases you're having a very long promise chain and the promise would resolve after all 5m promises are being resolved. In the first case the `.then()` inside `on('end')` as the last chained promise. Aren't those two the same thing?

Comment: @Shih-MinLee No, if you're not changing `p` then all callbacks are attached to the very same promise (the `Promise.resolve()`). That's not a long chain, it's a tree. And all callbacks will run immediately (as soon as `Promise.resolve()` is resolved), *not waiting for each other*.

Answer (score 1):

Well you want the promises to run in parallel, so can not chain them.

```
allp = [];
....
.on('data', (row) => {
    ...
    allp.push( p.then(() => {...}) );
}
...
.on('end', () => {
Promise.all(allp).then(() => {})
```

Of course you are creating one Promise for each event.

If you need to free the promises before the end, then you need to do this yourself.

Since you do not seem to be interested in the return value of the promises, but only in their side effects (increasing count), you could do

```
.on('data', (row) => {
    ...
    if (allp.length > 50) allp = [Promise.all(allp).then(()=>null)];
    allp.push( p.then(() => {...}) );
}
```

That way the 50 promises will be grouped, and once they resolve, they are replaced by a single promise (which will go into the next 50...)

The `.then(()=>null)` ensures the resulting array from Promise.all is discarded too. (Instead ONE promise for null will be in allp)

This does depend on the implementation of Promise.all. If Promise.all releases each promise as it resolves (and as the result is available) then this is perfect.

If Promise.all awaits all 50 promises, and then releases them all, then this still works, unless each group of 50 has one extremely long running promise.

---

You can use the anti pattern of a deferred promise.

Create one deferred promise at start.

```
var resolve;
var asyncRunningCount = 1; // start with 1
var p2 = new Promise(function() {
    resolve = arguments[0];
});
```

In the on data

```
.on('data', (row) => {
    ...
    asyncRunningCount++;
    p.then(() => {work}) )
    .then(() { 
        asyncRunningCount--; 
        if (asyncRunningCount == 0) resolve(); // no more tasks running
    } );
}

.on('end', () => {
    asyncRunningCount--; 
    // remove the 1 that was set on start. No more new tasks will be added
    if (asyncRunningCount == 0) resolve(); // no more tasks running
    p2.then(() => { all done })
```

The value 1 at startup prevents p2 from being resolved, if the count of running tasks temporarily drops to 0.

In on(end) the 1 is decremented. If all tasks are finished asyncRunningCount will be 0. This can happen by the decrement in on(end), or by a decrement in on(data).

p2.then, will run when all tasks are finished.

All other promises will be freed when they finish.
In fact in on(data) you don't need promises. Just start your async task, and when the async task is done decrement asyncRunningCount, and check for 0.

---

This still means if the data comes in very fast, that lots of promises start in parallel.
But if you don't start the promises, then you need to store the incoming data, so memory will be used either way.

Comment: Yes, both solutions would work, but why so complicated? In the first approach - why wait for 50 promises to accumulate in the array, instead of doing the `Promise.all` every time? In the second approach - no reason to use the deferred antipattern, just move the whole event emitter thing inside the `new Promise` callback. (Of course, even then it's still the reinventing `Promise.all` antipattern :D)

Comment: If you do Promise.all for *every* event (except the 1st maybe, as at that time there is only one) then you create twice (one less than twice) as many promises, as you would if you did not use Promise.all at all. Yes they are all freed as soon as they finish, so memory is not the issue. But execution time could become an issue...

Comment: As long as it has linear time&memory complexity I usually don't care :-) The execution time is bound by the asynchronous work (`delay(5)` in the OP's example), the additional promise will hardly matter.

Comment: The promises are actually doing sync stuff inside. If that's the case there's no difference in terms of performance compared to running all the promises one by one I guess?

Comment: If the promise do *only* sync stuff, then you can just run the code directly in the "on data".
But then I wonder why the counts did not add up at first.
Javascript defaults to single thread. So while the "on data" is running, nothing else runs. No other data is read until "on data" returns.
A Promise usually starts immediately upon its creation, so the then handler is immediately executed. The promise (and "on data") return when the promise goes async. But if that never happens....